# Unknown Filesystem Error after VirtualBox Disk resize

Tags: 12.04, grub2, virtualbox, boot-failure, grubrescue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Grub rescue - error: unknown filesystem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119597/grub-rescue-error-unknown-filesystem)

I was using *Ubuntu 12.04 x64* as a *Virtual Box* guest. Because I started with it just to do some tests, the VM was created just with 10 GB but grown fast, then I wanted resizing it. Of course, I was a fully noob... No backup before doing it.

After some reading, I thought it would be so simple as:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd MY_DISK.vdi --resize 81920
```

Unfortunately, no boot:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Then I tried many suggestions, including **Boot-Repair** as described here: [grub rescue prompt after install installing Ubuntu in a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139121/grub-rescue-after-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-dual-boot).

Nothing has worked. It seens that my Linux partition isn't there anymore?!
Here is the [Pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1149797/) with all the information collected by Boot-Repair.

And the last try, the **GParted Live CD** can't also recover any data, saying that there isn't data on any partition. Well, I should just give up? Or some way to recover this disk?

Answer (score 0):

First, make a backup of the current disk. While it's not clear how resizing the disk would cause this, lets hope that it's a simple problem of the partition table being out of sync with where on disk your filesystems start and stop. If it's just the partition table being out of sync, then you can correct this via testdisk by following the tutorial at http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step (stop when you get to the ntfs boot sector recovery, since that's not the problem you're trying to solve).

Answer (score 0):

The maximum size of a Virtual-box .vdi disk is 30 GB you you tried to set it as 80 GB , i do not really know yet how to fix this, but my guess is that you have to find some way to reset the size of the virtual-box .vdi disk down to or below the max-size limit.

Comment: No. The maximum size is actually up to 2TB.

Comment: This is not an answer!!!