# Grub can't find device on boot resulting in Grub Rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, ssd

So I have 2 hard drives a HDD 320GB and a SSD 20GB. Before I had Windows 7 on the HDD and Ubuntu on the SSD but wanted to get rid of windows and reinstall a clean Ubuntu on the SSD then use the HDD for storage.

So I deleted everything from the HDD and set up the SSD with 18GB ext4 and 2GB Swap and installed Ubuntu on the 18GB ext4. Though now when I boot up I get "Error: No such device  Grub Rescue"

I have a live USB and I ran the Boot Repair following these instructions - [grub rescue prompt after install installing Ubuntu in a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139121/grub-rescue-after-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-dual-boot) - it says successful though still have the same problem. This is the given URL from Boot Repair - http://paste.ubuntu.com/1257988/

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is that the grub you are running is the old one on the HDD, instead of the new one on SDD. Check that the BIOS boot order has the SDD before the HDD.  If that order is not available, install grub again to the HDD.