# Boot error after installing Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

**English**

I installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, but when I boot without using the cd the following error occurs:

```
Error: File not found
grub rescue>
```

And then I do not know what else to do, can someone help me, I need it a lot.

---

**Português**

Eu instalei o Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, mais ao iniciar sem utilizar o cd o erro abaixo ocorre:

```
Error: File not found
grub rescue>
```

E ai eu não sei mais o que fazer, alguém pode me ajudar estou precisando muito.

Answer (score 0):

I must reply in English. Sorry! I frequently have a similar problem. Nearly every time I have installed Ubuntu since 2011, grub is damaged and the computer won't boot. Is your boot disk an SSD?

The usual answer is to use `boot-repair` as in this post: [grub rescue prompt after install installing Ubuntu in a dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139121/grub-rescue-prompt-after-install-installing-ubuntu-in-a-dual-boot) You can also reinstall grub by hand, using a command terminal. This is what I do... often... but a lot of people swear by boot-repair.